# How can I groupby month and day part of the date column so I get 365 groups for an year

Tags: pandas

I have temperature data from 2004-2015. This is the head() of my dataframe:

```
            ID       Date Element  Data_Value
0  USC00084412  3/22/2014    TMIN         200
1  USC00087760  5/19/2010    TMIN         217
2  USC00087020  12/6/2005    TMAX         272
3  USW00012888   9/7/2009    TMIN         228
4  USR0000FCAC  6/28/2010    TMIN         250
```

I need to groupby month and day part of the 'Date' column, so I can get the max 'Data_Value' for each group. It will be 365 groups. Please help.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.Date.dt.strftime('%m-%d')).Data_Value.max()`

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple solutions, it depends what need:

```
#first convert colum to datetimes
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Solution for new columns `Month` and `Day` with max value `Data_Value` by aggregate [`GroupBy.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.month.rename('Month'), 
                  df['Date'].dt.day.rename('Day')])['Data_Value'].max().reset_index()

print (df1)
   Month  Day  Data_Value
0      3   22         200
1      5   19         217
2      6   28         250
3      9    7         228
4     12    6         272
```

Or months with days in string:

```
df2 = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))['Data_Value'].max().reset_index()
print (df2)
    Date  Data_Value
0  03-22         200
1  05-19         217
2  06-28         250
3  09-07         228
4  12-06         272
```

Or if need all rows by maximum of `Data_Value` column with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df3 = df.loc[df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'))['Data_Value'].idxmax()]
print (df3)
            ID       Date Element  Data_Value
0  USC00084412 2014-03-22    TMIN         200
1  USC00087760 2010-05-19    TMIN         217
4  USR0000FCAC 2010-06-28    TMIN         250
3  USW00012888 2009-09-07    TMIN         228
2  USC00087020 2005-12-06    TMAX         272
```